# MySQL Commandline client crashing after entering the Password

Tags: mysql, mysql-command-line-client

I just installed MySQL on my new Laptop and everything worked perfectly, but as soon as I pasted in the old databases from the same version of MySQL it began having problems. I restarted my Laptop and now when I try to fill in my Password the Client closes itself and not even the Workbench is able to connect to it. I also tried re-configuring but my Installer always marks my password as false. As soon as I uninstall and reinstall everything works fine until I restart the Server or my Laptop.

I tried resetting my password but it didn't change anything.

Comment: What is the exact error message you are getting when you try to connect?

Comment: I dont even get an error it just closes the window

Comment: Could it be that as you restored the databases you also restored the table used by MySQL to save the passwords. so use the password you set for the now restored database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot connect to your MySQL for some reason, which seems to be related to your user credentials. You will need to uninstall MySQL first, reinstall it and make sure everything works even after restarting your server. Do not do anything else at this point. This will be the very first checkpoint, which will confirm that you are successfully installing MySQL and connecting to it.

Now, you will need to carefully study the scripts/installers you want to execute and find specifically the parts that are doing user access, user privilege or other changes. Make sure that you understand what your new user credentials will be, save those values for yourself, update any connections, including Workbench accordingly.

Finally, look at how your programs are trying to connect to MySQL and see whether there is anything incorrect. Of course, during the process, you can always create hy-privileged users.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem. I just imported all the stuff like before and before restarting the server i changed the root password in the MySQL Workbench and now everything works fine.